# Why are most physical laws dependent on small powers?

Tags: laws-of-physics

The equation with the highest exponent I could find was the coefficient of energy loss of light scattered [in an optical fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering#In_optical_fibers):
$$
{\displaystyle \alpha _{\text{scat}}={\frac {8\pi ^{3}}{3\lambda ^{4}}}n^{8}p^{2}kT_{\text{f}}\beta }
$$
which has a power of $8$ on $n$, the index of refraction.

My question is *why* is this an outlier? Most physical laws I can think of only scale at most to the power $\pm 3$, so why would seeing an exponent of say, $50$ be regarded as possibly unphysical? I have seen the answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162883/why-do-most-formulas-in-physics-have-integer-and-rational-exponents), which are close, but don't answer my question.

Stated another way, is there any reason why the magnitude of the highest order exponent in a formula is inversely correlated to how commonly such an exponent appears in any given formula?

Comment: Some other examples of high powers are stellar nucleosynthesis rates, where for example for [triple alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process) process has a rate that goes like $T^{40}$.

Comment: Don't forget that there are many physical laws which contain exponential functions, and an exponential grows or decays faster than *any* power. In one sense, something which changes very fast with a high power, but not exponentially, is a weird special case, since fundamental forces that act over "large" distances (e.g. gravitation or electrostatics) follow inverse square laws.

Comment: The [Lennard-Jones Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) has a $12th$ power