# Why are so many physical laws expressed in terms of *integer* powers of some quantities?

Tags: laws-of-physics

Why are so many fundamental physical laws expressed in terms of *integer* powers of some quantities? I'd expect this to be a very, very unlikely occorrance, since the Nature doesn't know that "we count by fingers".

Comment: This might help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162883/

Comment: It looks definitely so, @ AkshatSharma. I'll go through the link. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do most formulas in physics have integer and rational exponents?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162883/)