# Physics formulas of the form $A \cdot x^r$ and $r$ not integer

Tags: education, mathematics, laws-of-physics

For a math class I am looking for some examples from physics for formulas of the form

$$
f(x) = A \cdot x^r
$$
and $r$ non-integer.

There are many simple examples where $r$ is an integer, but I didn't find so much so far for noninteger $r$. Only the period of a mathematical pendulum $T = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$ where $r$ would be $0.5$ (or $-0.5$ depending on wether you want do take $l$ or $g$ the role of $x$ above) and also adiabants in thermodynamics.

So are there other (simple) examples?

Comment: You might want to look at the physics of phase-transition theory, things like Critical exponents and universality classes...

Comment: Check the binding energy in nuclear physics for the liquid drop model https://www.nuclear-power.com/nuclear-power/fission/liquid-drop-model/

Comment: Is x supposed to be a variable or a constant?

Comment: $x$ should be a variable.

Comment: Area of a circle $~A=\pi\,r^2\quad\Rightarrow~r\propto A^{1/2}~$ Sphere volume $~r\propto V^{1/3}$

Comment: Beat me to it. Similar for $d = 1/2 at^2$. There must be many such examples.

Comment: @mmesser314 that's with integer $r$. Ok, you could solve it for $t$.

Comment: @Eli Thats not a physics example.

Comment: @Julia what is the difference to your example ? $~\frac lg~$ is constant ?

Comment: do you want analytical expressions (difficult: not easily integratable...) or just phenomenological examples from physics ?

Comment: List-of-stuff questions are off-topic on this site. Questions should have a specific answer.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162883/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Check out equations (5.48) and (5.50) [here](https://thesis.library.caltech.edu/4296/1/Peters_pc_1964.pdf), with exponents 12/19, 870/2299, -67/19, and 1181/2299 arising from one of the simplest physical systems: two gravitating point masses.

Comment: The unnumbered equation after (5.48) has the simple $Ax^r$ form, with $r=12/19$.

Answer (score 2):

Third Kepler's law: An object's orbital period $T$ squared is proportional to the the semi-major axis of its orbit $a$ cubed:
$$T^2=\frac{4\pi^2}{G(M+m)}a^3$$

Comment: Thanks, good example for $r = 1,5$