# Why don't we define time derivative of acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, calculus, jerk

When we started the study of kinematics we defined position and its change with respect to time. After that we defined time derivative of velocity which gave us acceleration.

These 3 concepts really helped us and we extended our study from kinematics to dynamics which provided us a simple relation between acceleration and force.

If we would have defined the time derivative of acceleration then what would we have got? What would have been its physical significance? How it would have helped us in study of dynamics?

I want to conclude my question by just asking that why don't we define the time derivative of acceleration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't we consider jerk in physics classes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160711/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are the higher derivatives (jerk, jounce) of position with respect to time used in physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189000/)

Comment: We call it jerk.  The time derivative of jerk (4th derivative of position with regards to time) is called jounce.  The 4th, 5th and 6th time derivatives are sometimes called "snap, crackle and pop".  This is a bit of a joke based on the names of Rice Krispies mascots.

Comment: jerk has definite practical meaning in engineering (e.g. for camshaft lobe design).