# Is there any case in physics where the equations of motion depend on high time derivatives of the position?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, equations-of-motion, jerk

For example if the force on a particle is of the form $ \mathbf F = \mathbf F(\mathbf r, \dot{\mathbf r}, \ddot{\mathbf r}, \dddot{\mathbf r}) $, then the equation of motion would be a third order differential equation, what will require us to know the initial conditions $ \mathbf r(0), \dot{\mathbf r}(0), \ddot{\mathbf r}(0) $ in order to get the exact solution.

EDIT: As akhmeteliless mentioned the Abraham–Lorentz force is an example for such force. But, how such force is possible if the Lagrangian contains only the coordinates and their first time derivatives? Shoudn't the equations of motion be second order differential equations?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119750/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Just a tip: if you feel that the question could be answered more fully, it's best not to accept an answer, because that tends to discourage people from posting another one. Personally, I would very much like to see a more comprehensive answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, the Dirac-Lorentz equation.

Comment: How such force is possible if the Lagrangian contains only the coordinates and their first time derivatives? Shoudn't the equations of motion be second order differential equations?

Comment: For what it's worth, it is written in a book by I. M. Ternov e.a. "Synchrotron Radiation and its Applications" (http://books.google.com/books?id=iRiXPad-tE8C&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22dirac+lorentz%22+lagrangian&source=bl&ots=T-zFFKuWTt&sig=Q-EVZHJFDy-HfMdO2OYmBQ8cJfU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tMMAUc2FKoSLrAGc4YH4Bg&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22dirac%20lorentz%22%20lagrangian&f=false ) that the Dirac-Lorentz equation "cannot be derived from a Hamiltonian or a Lagrangian, because it takes into account the radiation frictional force and thus describes a nonconservative system." I am not sure, but...

Answer (score 2):

The radiation-reaction force does not really describe fundamental physics.  It's a semi-classical attempt to describe a fundamentally quantum mechanical process.  This is why a seemingly simple question:  does a uniformly accelerating charge radiate? can lead to almost endless debate.  So caveat lector. But it is the standard problem involving jerk, the time derivative of acceleration.

Comment: Any other classical (or non-classical) problems involving jerk?

Comment: Not that I can think of Andrey, but I haven't googled it.

Answer (score -1):

The  general form of Equation of Motion in fact should be a 3rd order differential Equation because only the 3rd derivative of Position vector with respect to time  has components along Tangent, Normal and  Bi-Normal  like that of the Force  which may have components along Tangent, Normal and Bi-normal.The 2nd derivative of Position Vector has components along only tangent and normal and hence can not always be equated to Force.The Newtons Law  2nd  Order differential Equation can not explain the motion of Electrons  in Spherical Domain in Hydrogen atom and one has to  assign mysterious Waves or mysterious uncertainties to describe the motion