# Why is acceleration not usually count as a state?

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration, velocity, determinism

Position, velocity and acceleration can vary over time. Although only position and velocity are usually count as states of the ODEs. Which makes me wonder why acceleration is not taken as a state?

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154456/

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451 and links therein.