# Areas of physics and physical scenarios where jerk comes up

Tags: applied-physics, jerk

I am a high-schooler and I learnt that the third derivative of displacement with respect to time$\left(\frac{d^3s}{dt^3}\right)$ is known as **jerk**. I am curious to know where does this come up in physics. I never encountered this while studying high school physics and that's why I'm keen on knowing its applications.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52024/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Check this article, it may help you https://doi.org/10.1088/0143-0807/37/6/065008