# Difference between first newton's law and second newton's law ?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, inertia

the first and second laws of newton are both **similar**, so why do we need the first law if it is the same as the second?

what is the big **difference** between these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Newton's first law necessary?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122231/)

Comment: @ACuriousMind : thank you for your response , I saw that link before I post this question , but I need more details

Comment: The 1st law gives an experimental definition/test/verification of what a straight line is in *this* 3D geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this has been answered many times already, anywhere on this site, the following holds:

**First law** *(existence of inertial reference frames)*

There exist in the universe some very particular reference frames where a point particle not subject to external forces moves in a straight line, i. e. $\dot{\textbf{p}}=0$.

---

**Second law** *(equation of motion in the above defined)*

In the very particular reference frames defined by the first law, whenever external forces act on the point particle, the equation of motion is of the form $\dot{\textbf{p}}= \textbf{F}(\textbf{r},\textbf{p})$.

I do not see how the two are similar. Also check this other [answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/219439/84488).