Is there any phenomenon where opposite reaction (Newton's 3rd Law) is not fulfilled?
I'm wondering if there is any case in nature/physics where it has been observed "where there is an action, there is not necessarily an exact equal and opposite reaction".
Or is there some way/case where one can diminish the equal and opposite reaction effect. I'm looking specifically in the area of fluid dynamics / aerodynamics, but it can be any area.

Usually one invokes E&M or relativity as examples of violating the third law, so I would be surprised to find one in fluid dynamics.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/467386/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405791/25301

All forces occur in pairs. There are no isolated forces. See; http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Newt.html
As stated in the link, there are no known exceptions.
Hope this helps

This is not true in relativistic theories.  Indeed, in relativity, where simultaneity is not an invariant property, Newton's Third Law is not even a well-defined statement.

@Buzz I don’t believe N3 is violated in SR inasmuch as it is only intended to apply when the forces occur simultaneously.  See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240053/griffiths-argument-that-newtons-third-law-is-invalid-in-special-relativity

I think it is necessary to add something about the forces one is speaking about. Forces of what on what?
