# Is there a "standard" Newton?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, definition, si-units, metrology

Basic SI units have definitions through experiments that seems to imply a pretty obvious setup.

Is there a standard experiment for calibrating Newtons?

The definition is the force needed to cause a 1m/s² acceleration of a 1 kg mass.  I can imagine obtaining a 1 kg mass.

However, it seems error-prone to try and directly measure acceleration.  If you mark out 2 consecutive meters (points A, B, and C) and then measure the time the object crosses each, then you can say you have 1 Newton if $\tfrac{1}{T(C)-T(B)}=1+\tfrac{1}{T(B)-T(A)}$.

But there are several objections to be raised about defining a Newton in terms of a mass, two distances and three times.

Back to the question: How do you (theoretically) calibrate Newtons from first definitions? Thanks

Comment: The Amp can be defined in terms of the Newton, or rather force per length of two conductors with current running through them. https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/current.html You're always going to have errors that's life

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70186/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @R.Rankin this is outdated https://www.bipm.org/en/measurement-units/rev-si/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute accelerometers (or gravimeters) do measure the acceleration of a dropped weight.  But instead of timing it between two points directly, the speed is measured by having it reflect a laser into an interferometer and timing the interference fringes.  Commercial devices are available that can measure local acceleration to one part in $10^{-8}$.

Wikipedia article on [Gravimeters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravimeter#Commercial_Absolute_gravimeters)

Once the local acceleration of gravity is known, force can be read from calibrated masses.

Conference paper on [Force and Torque measurements](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285228167_Mechanical_metrology_Force_and_Torque)