# Determining mass and force separately

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, definition

I have been thinking.. How can we measure the mass of the body separately from the force? Or should we measure the force and acceleration? But by which means can we gauge our equipment e.g. some spring that we use to measure? So if we could measure the force and acceleration separately we could determine the relation of Newtons 2nd law. Any thoughts?

This is my idea. We can define the measure of the force exerted by some weigh on the spring by the change of the lenght of the spring. Then we check with one weigh how the lenght of the spring changes. We then check with the other one if it is of the same weigh. Then we somehow check that one of the bodies does not influence the other that is that two bodies together on the spring exert double the force. Then we conclude that by the measure of spring lenght change we can measure the effect of the weight. Then, we can compare this to some other stuff that causes the same thing...extension of the spring. Then we use the spring to move the body with constant force which is shown by the springs extension.We measure the acceleration and we vary the force to see the connection...then we define the mass to be a property of the body in question which is defined by F over a. Is there anything wrong with this reasoning?

So a new edit. We can define mass using this idea of the force. So the mass is quantified in this way and now we have defined kg as N over metar per second squared. But this is not how it is done. Newton is defined via the kg and m/s2...So, how? ANd why? Could we just say, ok, here we have some inertia, lets call it 1 kg.So lets see How is acceleration connected to this inertia? And this factor that we get we call force? Help me please or I will die.. :-)

Comment: The weighing machines which are generally used calculate the force exerted by the object on them. Since the acceleration is known ($9.8 m/s^2$), they give the mass reading.

Comment: They are based on Newton's Second Law. How will you use it to verify the law itself?

Comment: How is acceleration known?

Comment: Measured by dropping the objects from a certain height, I guess.

Comment: So, we measure the acceleration and use this weighing machine, that is a bit oscure....what concrete way is there to define the force separately so as to be able to confirm 2nd  law?

Comment: Why is that obscure? Maybe you can't just verify newton's law using this arrangement.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/340890/20427

Comment: Thank you for this link, its actually on the same way of thinking as mine..