# What is the true quantitative definition of "force"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, definition

Newton's second Law of Motion states that for a point mass, $\vec F = m \vec a$. This is a **law** and **not** a definition. So, this **law** only makes sense if all the physical quantities appearing in this law are **pre-defined**.

$\vec a$ is pre-defined because $\vec a =\frac {d \vec v}{dt}=\frac{d^2 \vec r}{dt^2}$, where $\vec v$ and $\vec r$ represent velocity vector and position vector respectively. $m$ is the mass of the concerned point mass and is one of the fundamental physical quantities so it is definitely pre-defined.

But what about force ? How do we define it quantitatively ? The only definition which I remember says that one newton is the amount of force required to accelerate $1$  $kg$ of body by $1$ $m/s^2$. But that is just defining force with $\vec F = m \vec a$, which is just circular reasoning.

So, what is "force" **really** ?? I mean ...... on a **fundamental level** ..... without using any kind of circular reasoning ..... how do we *actually* define the term "force" **quantitatively**???? I mean, surely there must be *some* way to define force, right ?

**EDIT :** Is it even possible to define force ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Newton's "laws" of motion laws or definitions of force and mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70186/)

Comment: @Quadro You said “This is a law and not a definition” I disagree that laws cannot be definitions. I would consider Newton’s 2nd law to be a definition of force

Comment: we can measure mass and acceleration, so they have a measurable quantity, since force equals mass times acceleration, force has a measurable quantity, a newton

Answer (score 0):

We don’t define “force” in general; we define specific forces as specific functions of position and velocity. For example, Newtonian gravitational force is $\mathbf{F}=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ and Lorentz force is $\mathbf{F}=q(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})$. Putting such forces into Newton’s Second Law then produces a differential equation of motion predicting how things move. There is no circularity when you think of force in this way.

Without a specific force law, force is simply “any interaction which makes an object accelerate”, which has little predictive usefulness. But with specific force laws, you can understand *in detail* and sometimes *to extreme precision* how the physical world works.

By following this approach, we have discovered that all phenomena that we observe are explainable in terms of only *four* fundamental forces: gravity, electromagnetism, the weak nuclear force, and the strong nuclear force. This is one of the greatest intellectual achievements of humankind.

Comment: How can a law based on force make sense if we do not know what force really is ? By the way, I did not downvote.

Comment: It makes sense because physics is about constructing mathematical models of reality that explain observation, not “knowing” what things “are”. We explain by calculating and predicting!

Comment: Thinking that $F=ma$ defines force is rather like thinking that $E=mc^2$ defines energy. Don’t do it. Both are *relationships*, not *definitions*.