# I don't understand how $F$ equals $ma$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

I am a beginner in Physics and currently doing laws of motion. So, I don't really understand how the second law is true. It's just that I don't understand how it makes sense.

So, we start with the assumption that a  and m are directly proportional to F. Now, how does it follow from it that F=ma where k=1 is the constant of proportionality ? All that proportionality implies is that with increase in a or m or both, the  force as well, increases or vice versa.

Comment: The way we use proportionality in daily life is not actual definition of proportionality. Just like the term Work in daily life and in physics.

Comment: You can basically think of it as just a definition. Someone realised that the quantity $ma$ might be quite useful, so a name was invented for it: Force.

Comment: @Rayhan suppose there is always an constant acceleration between two bodies. One's mass is double than the other's mass. So, you have to apply double force than the other on it so that the acceleration can remain constant. That's all from where the proportionality comes.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70186/50583

Comment: @Steeven no. Force is obtained from gravitational law or from Hooke's law or Coulomb law etc. It has properties such as 3rd law. 2nd law is not a definition of force.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically Directly proportional means if you increase acceleration twice force will also increase two times and similarly for mass.

So assuming mass m to be constant,
$$F \propto a$$
Similarly, assuming acceleration to be constant
$$F \propto m$$
Now if you increase a x times and m y times then by above proportionality F will increase by $x.y$ times. For understanding this you can assume the process to happen in steps, e.g. First increasing the mass and then increasing the acceleration.

So
$$F \propto ma$$
$$F =k .ma$$
Now in SI unit system, unit of force is defined by taking k=1, I.e. 1 N forces is standardised to be force needed for moving 1 kg mass with $1 ms^{-1}$ acceleration
So k=1

Comment: I knew it already that proportionality in maths is different from that used in common parlance. So anyway, how do we know that force increases x-times when we increase mass by x times, and the same happens with acceleration ? Like, how do we know they're really proportional in that mathematical sense ? Pardon me if the question is stupid btw.

Comment: @HemantKumar you should mention that force is directly proportional to mass when acceleration is constant and also directly proportional to acceleration when mass is constant.

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas I have edited that. Still 'ma'can be assumed to be changing in steps e.g. First changing m and then a.

Comment: @Rayhan through experiments, i.e changing mass and measuring effect of it and so on. Acceleration is something actual, while force is just a quantity that simplifies calculations by taking into account the effect of mass. It can be wrong just like most theories, but it holds the idea best until now.

Answer (score 3):

> So, we start with the assumption that a and m are directly proportional to F.

That is not true. Besides not being an assumption, the statement should have been:

*Acceleration $a$ is proportional to net force $F$ with the coefficient of proportionality being the mass $m$*.

I don't see the point to have two constants of proportionality between $F$ and $a$ is in $F = (k m) a$ as you can roll it into one. Experimentally it has been proven that the proportionality mass $m$ (called internal mass) is identical to the gravitational mass. See [Eötvös experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_experiment).

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way. You can do various things to an object to make it change its velocity. For example, you can push it, pull on it, put a magnet by it (if it is magnetic), drop it and so on. We give the effect of all those methods a common label, which is 'force'.

If you apply a force to one body, and then apply the same force to two identical bodies fastened together, the rate of change in velocity that the force brings about in the second case is half the rate that it brings about in the first. Through experiments of that sort you can find that the more mass you apply a force to, the smaller the effect it has in terms of the rate of change of velocity.

You can do another set of experiments in which you apply different forces to the same object. You will find from those that the more force you apply to an object, the greater is the effect on the rate of change of its velocity.

Experimentally, therefore, you can show that there is a directly proportional relationship between the force you apply to a given mass and the rate of change in velocity that results from the application of the force. If you define your units sensibly, you can make the constant of proportion one.

So, practically what Newton's Second Law means is that if you subject a range of different bodies to a range of different forces, in each case the resulting acceleration will be related to the size of the force and the mass of the object by the formula F=ma.

Answer (score 2):

Newton’s second law says that acceleration is proportional to Force. The proportionality constant is the mass. In a Newtonian context this *is the definition* of mass.

Answer (score 1):

Let F=mak, redefine a new quantity F'=F/k. There, now you have F'=ma.

These ideas are mutually defined. Yes, in a metaphysical sense all we observe is some proportionality but when we sit down to define quantities, we can make such convenient choices. In fact, in more advanced physics, this is the idea of setting physical constants like c=1

Answer (score 1):

Essentially speaking, Newton's 2nd law states that the force applied by a body is equal to the rate of change of its momentum.

Let's say the initial momentum of a body was $mv$, m being its mass and v its velocity, and finally it comes down to $mu$, where u is the reduced (assume) velocity.

The change in momentum is obviously $mv-mu = m(v-u)$.

We assume this change in momentum takes place over a time t. By definition of 'rate', the rate of change of the momentum is then $\frac{mv-mu}{t}$ = $\frac{m(v-u)}{t}$.

Acceleration is defined as the rate of change of velocity, or in other words:

$\frac{v-u}{t} = a$

Plugging this in, we get the rate of change of momentum to be $ma$, which according to Newton's definition is equal to the force. Mathematically:

$F = \frac{m(v-u)}{t} = ma$

To look at it another way, Newton found that:

$F \propto a$

$F \propto m$

thus:

$F \propto ma$

To remove the proportionality sign, we needed a constant of proportionality, which, to define 1N as 1kg times 1m/s$^2$, Newton took to be 1, giving us:

$F = ma$

Comment: I think OP had a clear understanding about it and OP just want to know why it is always proportional to force.

Answer (score 0):

@rayhan, So basically they say that Force is the derivative of momentum w.r.t. time (im sorry if you haven't yet studied basic calculus and cheers if you have),

So  *F=dP/dt*,

and we can write it like , *F= d(m . v)/dt*

so by applying the product rule we get, *F= [ dm/dt * v ]+[ dv/dt * m]*

now if the mass of the body is **constant** (it only works for constant masses) the *dm/dt term = 0*,

so we get *F = dv/dt * m*

where *dv/dt= acceleration*,

so **F = ma**

and there you have it, **f=ma**

sorry if it's hard to read or to understand, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Fortunately, I have done basic calc and am already familiar with this derivation. It's just that the other way of arriving at F=ma, by assuming that Force is  what makes an object change its velocity, and it's directly proportional to m and a, didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @rayhan hope you find it easy.

Comment: the same problem was with me, I didn't find it very logical just to like equate them by saying "it's by definition" that's why I sticked to the calc way. anyways thank you!

Comment: Mate, are you from India btw ?

Comment: @rayhan Yeah, are you?

Comment: Yeah, I am. I am in school btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138474/discussion-between-sciencenium-and-rayhan).