# How to evaluate a non-banal derivate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, differentiation, calculus, non-linear-schroedinger

I need to evaluate the following derivate:

$$\frac{dF}{d\Psi} = \frac{d}{d\Psi}\left[\beta\Delta\Psi+\alpha\left|\Psi\right|^2\Psi+\mu\Psi-i\vec{v}\cdot\bar{\nabla}\Psi\right]$$

where $\Psi$ is a complex eigenfunction $\Psi(x,y,t)$. In particular I am not sure on how to evaluate the derivate when there is also the Laplacian of Psi and the gradient.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Ps. I am doing this numerically, so actually I don't know the shape of Psi. I only need to know how to evaluate this derivate with respect of Psi, so that I can then execute it numercally in a Fortran code.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109518/derivation-of-euler-lagrange-equations-for-lagrangian-with-dependence-on-second