# QFT by Schwartz Problem 3.1 Solution

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

I am having trouble while solving in the Problem 3.1 of the QFT book by Schwartz.

**Problem**

Find the generalization of the [Euler-Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for general higher-order Lagrangians of the form $\mathcal{L}[\phi, \partial_\mu \phi, \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi, \ldots]$.

I have tried to solve this problem. But got stuck. I will be glad if anyone can help me solving this. The steps which I done so far is given below.

Let, the action is
\begin{equation}\label{S}
S=\int d^4x\,{\cal L}
\,,
\end{equation}
where ${\cal L}$ denotes a Lagrangian density which may depend on $\phi$ and up to its $N$-th order space-time derivatives.  In other words, we have
\begin{equation}\label{L}
{\cal L}={\cal L}(\phi,\partial_{\mu_1}\phi,
\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\phi,\dots,\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\dots\partial_{\mu_N}\phi)
\,.
\end{equation}

The classical dynamics of the system is determined by demanding the action $S$ to remain stationary under arbitrary variations of $\phi$ and its derivatives, vanishing at the integration boundary.

\begin{align}
    & \delta S\\
    = & \delta \left(\int d^4x ~\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_{\mu_1}\phi,
\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\phi,\dots,\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\dots\partial_{\mu_N}\phi)\right)\\
= & \int d^4 x~ \delta \mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_{\mu_1}\phi,
\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\phi,\dots,\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\dots\partial_{\mu_N}\phi)\\
= 
& \int d^4 x~ \left(\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial\phi}
\delta\phi
+
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu_1}\phi)}
\delta(\partial_{\mu_1}\phi)
+
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\phi)}
\delta(\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\phi)
 + \dots +
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\dots\partial_{\mu_N}\phi)}
\delta(\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\dots\partial_{\mu_N}\phi)\right) \label{eqn: action2}
\end{align}
Define,
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu_{(n)}}\phi \equiv \partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}\dots\partial_{\mu_n}\phi
\end{equation}
where $\partial_{\mu_{(0)}}$ denotes no derivative at all, that is, $\partial_{\mu_{(0)}}\phi\equiv\phi$.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\delta S = & \int d^4x~ \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu_{(n)}}\phi)}
\delta(\partial_{\mu_{(n)}}\phi)\\
= & \int d^4x~ \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu_{(n)}}\phi)}
\partial_{\mu_{(n)}} (\delta \phi)\\
\end{align}

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109518/2451

Comment: Integrate by parts

Comment: @Qmechanic I want the solution in the context of classical field theory not classical mechanics.

Comment: @Prahar Can you please show detailed steps?

Comment: @darkphysics - no, it's a homework problem. We do not provide solutions here.