# Ostrogradski’s theorem's proof

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

I am looking for a proof of the next theorem:

"If the higher order time derivative Lagrangian is non-degenerate, there is at least one
linear instability in the Hamiltonian of this system."

Where Non-degeneracy means that the highest time derivative term can be expressed in terms
of canonical variables.

Comment: Related: genneth's answer to [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451) Phys.SE question.

Comment: I prefer a reference where the theorem and its proof is discussed therein.

Comment: I believe [this](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ostrogradsky's_theorem_on_Hamiltonian_instability) answers your question.