# Lagrangians with higher derivatives than Klein-Gordon

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, klein-gordon-equation

Has anyone ever tried to work with Lagrangians involving higher derivatives?

The *Klein-Gordon* Lagrangian only involves $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})^2$ and $\nabla^2$ terms, what about third and higher derivatives?

What is so special about the Klein Gordon field anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are there only derivatives to the first order in the Lagrangian?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/)

Comment: Relativistic invariance?