# Energy-momentum tensor transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem, boundary-terms

> I've been trying to find how the energy-momentum tensor changes if we add a total derivative to the lagrangian: $$L\to L+\mathrm d_\mu X^\mu.\tag{1}$$

From the answer key:  $$T^{\mu\nu}\to T^{\mu\nu}+\partial_\lambda F^{\lambda\mu\nu}\tag{2}$$
Where $$F^{\lambda\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial X^\lambda}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\partial^\nu\phi -\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial(\partial_\lambda\phi)}\partial^\nu\phi.\tag{3}$$
Is the above answer right?
I'm not able to get this result! any help?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which book?

Comment: actually my friend gave me this result I'm not able to find it in any text book

Answer (score 3):

1. Let us assume that the new and old Lagrangian density $${\cal L} \quad\to\quad {\cal L} +\sum_{\mu=0}^3 d_{\mu} {\cal X}^{\mu}\tag{A}$$ does not depend *explicitly* on the spacetime point $x$. Then [Noether's 1st theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem) states that
   the [canonical stress-energy-momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) (SEM) [tensor density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) 
   $$ {\cal T}^{\mu}{}_{\nu} ~:=~ \frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial( \partial_{\mu}\phi)}\partial_{\nu}\phi- \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}{\cal L}\tag{B}$$
   is conserved on-shell
   $$ d_{\mu}{\cal T}^{\mu}{}_{\nu}~\approx~0. \tag{C} $$
   (In this answer we use calligraphic letters to denote densities.)
2. Note that OP's formula (3) suggests that the vector density ${\cal X}^{\mu}(\phi(x),\partial\phi(x))$ depends on spacetime derivatives $\partial\phi(x)$ of the field $\phi(x)$. This would imply that the Lagrangian density (A)  depends on higher spacetime derivatives $\partial^2\phi(x)$. This in turn goes against common physics lore, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.
3. Let us for simplicity assume that the vector density ${\cal X}^{\mu}(\phi(x))$ does *not* depends on spacetime derivatives $\partial\phi(x)$. Then
   $$  d_{\nu} {\cal X}^{\mu}~=~\frac{\partial {\cal X}^{\mu}(\phi)}{\partial\phi}\partial_{\nu}\phi.\tag{D} $$
   And hence the canonical SEM tensor density (B)
   changes as 
   $$ {\cal T}^{\mu}{}_{\nu}\quad\to\quad {\cal T}^{\mu}{}_{\nu}+ d_{\nu} {\cal X}^{\mu} -\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}  d_{\lambda} {\cal X}^{\lambda}
   ~=~{\cal T}^{\mu}{}_{\nu}+d_{\lambda} {\cal F}^{\lambda\mu}{}_{\nu}, \tag{E}$$
   where the improvement term is
   $$ {\cal F}^{\lambda\mu}{}_{\nu}~=~ \delta^{\lambda}_{\nu}{\cal X}^{\mu}-\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}{\cal X}^{\lambda}~=~ - {\cal F}^{\mu\lambda}{}_{\nu} \tag{F}.$$
4. In particular, the energy density 
   $$ {\cal T}^0{}_0\quad\to\quad {\cal T}^0{}_0 -  \sum_{i=1}^3 d_i {\cal X}^i \tag{G} $$
   changes with a spatial 3-divergence, so that the energy 
   $$ {\cal E} ~=~\pm \int_V \! d^3x ~ {\cal T}^0{}_0 \tag{H}$$
   is unchanged under normal circumstances by the divergence theorem. Here we have used the Minkowski sign convention $(\pm,\mp,\mp,\mp)$.