# Ambiguities in the energy-momentum tensor

Tags: energy-conservation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory, boundary-terms

There is a problem 3.3 in [Schwartz’s QFT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107034736):

> Ambiguities in the energy-momentum tensor:
>
> (a) If you add a total derivative to Lagrangian ${\cal{L}} \rightarrow {\cal{L}} + \partial_\mu X^\mu$, how does the energy-momentum tensor change?
>
> (b) Show that the total energy $Q = \int d^3x \; {\cal{T^{00}}}$ is invariant under such changes

Given the definition of energy-momentum tensor:

$$
{\cal{T}}^\mu{}_\nu = \sum_n \frac{\partial{\cal{L}}}{\partial \left( \partial_\mu \phi_n \right)} \partial_\nu \phi_n - g_{\mu\nu} {\cal{L}}
$$

It changes as:

$$
\delta {\cal{T}}^\mu{}_\nu =  \sum_n \left( \partial_\rho \frac{\partial{X^\rho}}{\partial \left( \partial_\mu \phi_n \right)} \right) \partial_\nu \phi_n - g_{\mu\nu} {\partial_\rho X^\rho}
$$

$T^{00}$ changes as:

$$
\delta {\cal{T}}^{00}= \sum_n \left( \partial_\rho \frac{\partial{X^\rho}}{\partial \dot{\phi_n}} \right) \dot{\phi_n} - \partial_\rho X^\rho
$$

From this point I’m stuck. The first term doesn’t seem to disappear at all after integration over space, and the second disappears only partially:

$$
\int d^3x \; \dot{X^0}
$$

So even if I’d have assumed that $X$ depends on position, and not on the fields - the total energy doesn’t seem to be invariant under it.

What is the best way to proceed forward with this?

Comment: See Weinberg's QFT, Vol.I, pages 305-306.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform There is another part few pages forward (p. 314) that works out Belinfante tensor. However, is it really something that the reader should be aware of to be able to solve this? The way the problem is constructed is that the next part should somehow lead the student to the Belinfante tensor.

Comment: That being said, the chapter is about Classical Field Theory, so the commutation relations presumably should not appear in the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257875/2451