# Transformation of the Stress-Energy tensor

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

My question is related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257875/energy-momentum-tensor-transformation) one. However in my case, the Lagrangian can depend on higher order derivatives (so the second point made doesn't hold). Can someone help me with it?