# Is there a deep reason why a non-relativistic Lagrangian does not have higher order derivatives?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

In classical mechanics non-relativistic Lagrangians rely only on the coordinates and their first derivatives to describe a physical system.

Is there a deep reason why particle acceleration etc does not make an appearance as a Lagrangian argument?

Comment: Great question! Does this post answer it?: [Why are there only derivatives to the first order in the Lagrangian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/)

Comment: yes, thank you!